# Passing props to a component inside a higher order component

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-leaflet, higher-order-components

I am trying to understand how to pass props to a component that is being wrapped by a higher order component.  I have a higher order component written like this:

```js
import React from 'react'

function withAuth(Layer){

   return class AuthenticatedHOC extends React.Component{

      componentDidMount(){
         if (!this.props.token){
            authenticateEsri()
         } 
      }

      render(){
         return (
            <>
               {this.props.token && <Layer {...this.props} />}
            </>
         )
      }

   }

}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   token: state.data.layers.esri.access_token
})

export default compose(
   connect(mapStateToProps),
   withAuth
)
```

Pretty simple.  The HOC checks if an auth token is in the redux store.  If its not, it makes an API call to get a token.  Once its in there, it renders the wrapped component with the auth token as a prop.  The average component that is used as the argument in this HOC looks like this:

```js
import { withLeaflet, MapControl } from "react-leaflet";
import * as EsriLeaflet from "esri-leaflet";
import withEsriAuth from './withAuth'

class Layer extends MapControl {
   createLeafletElement(props) {
      const layer = EsriLeaflet[props.layerType]({
         ...props
      })
      return layer;
   }

   componentDidMount() {
      const { map } = this.props.leaflet;
      this.leafletElement.addTo(map);
   }
}

export default withEsriAuth(withLeaflet(Layer))
```

Some layers require an auth token, and some don't.  Passing a token to a layer that doesn't require it causes an error, as does not passing a token to a layer that requires one.  What I want to be able to do is separate the `withEsriAuth` from the `EsriLeafletLayer` component.  Rather than have the `EsriLeafletLayer` wrapped in `withEsriAuth` every time, I want to be able to decide whether or not use the auth HOC each time I declare a `Layer`.  As it stands now, I can declare a component like this:

```
<Layer url="somelayerurl.com" opacity={0.5} />
```

And it will run the auth every time.  I'd rather `export default withLeaflet(Layer)`, and then declare something like this:

```js
withAuth( <Layer url="somelayerurl.com" opacity={0.5} /> )
```

However this is not working - it is telling me that a function is not a valid react child.  I know something looks funky with that syntax, and that there must be a more proper way to write this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could you include the import statements from the top of your files?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question to include these lines.